# Why x++ is not x+1 when logged on JS console?

Tags: javascript

I am extremely new to JS and wanted to try the following.

```js
var dev=4;
console.log(dev++);
```

I expected the output to be 5, but the output was 4. Can not understand the reason.

Comment: x++ is post increment, the increment is done after the value is "read" - think of it as read and return x, then add 1 - ie increment "post" access

Comment: ^^ and if you did want to see 5 in your example, you'd use the *pre* version: `++dev`, which means "increment it, then read the result and use it". If the `++` (or `--`) is *before* the operand (`dev`), the increment (or decrement) is done before the read; if it's after, it's done after.

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Comment: use `console.log(++dev)`

Answer (score 2):

dev++ returns dev, then adds one to it

++dev adds one to it, then returns it (your goal)

Answer (score 0):

`x++` first uses the current value, then increments its value.

`++x` first increments its value, then uses the value of the variable. This is the notation you're probably after.